# How to send email from jenkins server

Tags: jenkins, mail-sender

I have developed a  web applications (WebApp) which has a mail listener and is waiting from a mail from my Jenkins server. How do I configure Jenkins server to send mail .
Assume that my  WebApp has a unique mail id allocated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- `http://<your.jenkins.server.url>/configure`
- Configure SMTP settings